# Dealing with secrets and source control

Tags: github

If I create a repo on github and include a secrets.js file in my project and include it in my .gitignore file and store all of my "secrets" in it, am i correct to assume that the public will not have access to those secrets?

Comment: Simple answer no. Easy way to do is go to your repository, then if the repository is private then no one except you can see it, but if your repository is public and the file `secrets.js` is in it, then everyone can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Git does not track the files which are included in `.gitignore` file and those files won't be shown on github, so your secrets wont be access by public